# Conditional removal of a period in abbreviations but not by sentence ending with python regular expression

Tags: python, regex

I have some sentences peppered with abbreviations. The goal is to remove `.` if it appears in an abbreviation such as "U.S.", but not if it is a period signal normal sentence ending. Specifically, the following test documents

```
docs = ['U.S.S.R. line-continued', 'u.s.s.r. line-continued', 'U.S.S.R. Title Case', 'end-of-sentence. New-sentence', 'end-of-sentence.']
```

should be converted into

```
['USSR line-continued', 'ussr line-continued', 'USSR Title Case', 'end-of-sentence. New-sentence', 'end-of-sentence.']
```

I was trying something like

```
[re.sub(r"((\w)\.){2,}", r"\1", doc) for doc in docs]
```

which keeps the characters if the "character-followed-by-period" pattern occurs more than once. But it does not work.

This works

```
[re.sub(r"(\w)\.(\w)\.(\w)?\.?(\w)?\.?", r"\1\2\3\4", doc) for doc in docs]
```

but it does not generalize if I have five or more characters with dots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a simpler way. Use this [regex](https://regex101.com/r/lVONmF/1):

```
import re
docs = ['U.S.S.R. line-continued', 'u.s.s.r. line-continued', 'U.S.S.R. Title Case', 'end-of-sentence. New-sentence', 'end-of-sentence.']
print ([re.sub(r"(?<!\w)([A-Za-z])\.", r"\1", doc) for doc in docs])
```

Output:

```
['USSR line-continued', 'ussr line-continued', 'USSR Title Case', 'end-of-sentence. New-sentence', 'end-of-sentence.']
```

Comment: Could you please explain the meaning of `(><!\w)` and why replace it by `\1` instead of `\2`? Thanks!

Comment: Replace single dots that are preceded by an uppercase/lowercase single letter provided the single letter is not immediately preceded by anything in the `\w` character set. The latter criterion is enforced by the negative look-behind assertion - `(?<!\w)`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that this expression or maybe a bit modified version of that might likely work:

```
((?:\w\.){2,})
```

#### Test with `re.findall`

```
import re

regex = r"((?:\w\.){2,})"

test_str = "docs = ['U.S.','U.S.S.R. line-continued', 'u.s.s.r. line-continued', 'U.S.S.R. Title Case', 'end-of-sentence. New-sentence', 'end-of-sentence.','U.S.S.R.U.S.S.R.U.S.S.R.U.S.S.R. line-continued']"

print(re.findall(regex, test_str))
```

#### Output

```
['U.S.', 'U.S.S.R.', 'u.s.s.r.', 'U.S.S.R.', 'U.S.S.R.U.S.S.R.U.S.S.R.U.S.S.R.']
```

#### Test with `re.finditer`

```
import re

regex = r"((?:\w\.){2,})"

test_str = "docs = ['U.S.','U.S.S.R. line-continued', 'u.s.s.r. line-continued', 'U.S.S.R. Title Case', 'end-of-sentence. New-sentence', 'end-of-sentence.','U.S.S.R.U.S.S.R.U.S.S.R.U.S.S.R. line-continued']
"

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):

    print ("Match {matchNum} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group()))

    for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
        groupNum = groupNum + 1

        print ("Group {groupNum} found at {start}-{end}: {group}".format(groupNum = groupNum, start = match.start(groupNum), end = match.end(groupNum), group = match.group(groupNum)))
```

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/nIS4Ng/1/), if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it, and in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/nIS4Ng/1/debugger), you can watch how it would match against some sample inputs step by step, if you like.